# P0171 2014 Ford Fusion

Tags: ford, dtc

2014 Ford Fusion with 2.0L Ecoboost.
Car is displaying CEL with a code of P0171.

At Idle in Closed Loop
LTFT is at 29%
STFT is around 0%
Downstream O2 is steady at around 0.7 volts
Not sure how to read the wideband O2 sensor.

At 2300 rpm
everything stays about he same.
LTFT is at 29%
STFT is around 0%
Downstream O2 is steady at around 0.7 volts
If it was a vacuum leak, I would expect the FT values to decrease.

I have checked for a vacuum leak in spite of the trim values not going down and have not found anything yet.

What else should I be looking at for this?

[image]

Comment: Might be not enough fuel vs. too much air . Have you checked fuel pressure? Also could be restricted exhaust like a plugged cat.

Comment: High side fuel pressure varies with demand but gets close to 2000psi during full throttle.
At full throttle the car accelerates nicely which does not correlate with a plugged cat so I kind of ruled that out.
Car does not have a fuel filter other than the sock in the tank.
I am currently thinking that there is a problem with the injectors.

Comment: 2000 p.s.i.????

Comment: Yes, the scan tools displays the low side and high side fuel pressures.
The fuel rail after the high pressure pump is reported in Kpa by the scan tool.
I have seen numbers for the high side fuel pressure rail as high as 13,000 to 14,000 kpa. Converting those numbers to psi results in numbers close to 2000 psi.

Comment: I have smoke tested for a vacuum leak without success. 
Both of the O2 sensors appear to be giving good readings.
I am currently leaning towards an injector problem.

Comment: Do you know if that is high enough fuel pressure? I don't know the specs, but wonder if it might be low.